# Selenium webDriver: Multiple test cases in a single Class?

Tags: selenium

I'm using Java and Selenium Webdriver, but there is something that I don't understand. Do I need to create separate classes for each test, or I just need to create one class and in that class have all my tests.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You might be interested in a [discussion that I started yesterday](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/16620/structuring-selenium-tests-to-avoid-duplication) on the same subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Unit)Test-runners wrap their tests in a class for execution. You can place multiple tests into a single class. Often an annotation is used to show the class method is a test. jUnit uses `@Test`, MStest uses `<TestMethod>` and nUnit uses `[Test]`

Personally I group tests that test the same part of the application into a single class. This way the class files do not become to big and I can add helper functions close to the tests.

Now you are thinking about how to structure your automated tests also be sure to read about [the Page Object pattern](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html). As it the current best practice in preventing code duplication in tests.

Comment: Great Niels! Thank you for your reply.
I also talked about this with my manager and he also suggested that if the tests are dependant, then use a single class for those dependant tests. If the tests are independent, then use more classes and just add them to the executable xml that run all the tests.